# How to change formatting of text in a beamer theorem-environment?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am making a beamer-presentation and I want to change the formatting of the text in a theorem-environment.

The text in a theorem is by default formatted in `\textit{}` or `\textsl{}`, but I want it to be formatted 'normally', i.e. I want to change the formatting to 'plain text'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer to your previous question, you can add `\normalfont` to the definition of the theorem block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Aalborg}

\uselanguage{danish}
\languagepath{danish}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Theorem}{Saetning}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
    }%
    \normalfont%
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
    \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
            text
        $a^2+b^2=c^2$ 
        \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \end{itemize}
        \label{pytagoras}
    \end{theorem}

    Theorem \ref{pytagoras}

    \begin{block}{Title Pythagoras}
        content...
        \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```